# How can I get user time and sys time in Visual C++?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Is there some API that equivalent with that in the time.h in linux systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions in time.h are standard - they are available in VC++ too. However, there is no standard function that differentiates between system and user time.

Comment: So how can I get these two time?

Comment: I'm not sure that Windows has such concepts.